# MultipartEntityBuilder HttpPost socket write error in java

Tags: java, file-upload, http-post, multipartentity, httppostedfilebase

I am trying file upload with httpPost request (by MultipartEntityBuilder) in java. But i get a **Software caused connection abort: socket write error**.

Here is my httpPost body (in wireShark)

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryWphJNFngxYSpEvNO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrf_token"

csrf:sjwzV6dOZaNFwc0jWVrNNcFvhM7uv3BK00vZ0hCgEUzi2cG7r7Arx0Q3UZKlXeaR
------WebKitFormBoundaryWphJNFngxYSpEvNO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imagefilename"; filename="myfile.bin"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

²qz‹ÁOOõMÓâg‘Ç`:----This area is file's binary code------Êëá‡/oåup
```

code side is:

```
            File file = new File(filePath);
            String message = csrf_token;
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            builder.addBinaryBody("imagefilename", file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, file.getName());
            builder.addTextBody("csrf_token", message, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);
//
            HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

and error:

[image]

Is there any idea? thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved the problem, thesee links are useful for answer

[here](https://enbiyakocbiyik.wordpress.com/2016/02/23/http-post-ile-fileupload-islemi/?frame-nonce=e4e0480887) is fileupload with http Client example

[here](https://enbiyakocbiyik.wordpress.com/2016/02/23/httpurlconnection-kullanarak-file-upload-islemi/) is fileupload too, with httpUrlConnection